# Apache Gateway to Dockerized FPM Container?

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have a dockerized app with a web fpm interface (monica:fpm-alpine), and a vps on the internet.

I want my vps to be an https gateway to this app.

I thought I could use a virtual host include file and apache mod_proxy to do this, but all I get is grief. The docker logs don't suggest a

This virtual host apache include file has:

```
ProxyPass / fcgi://localhost:9432/
ProxyPassReverse / fcgi://localhost:9432/
```

And I've mapped port 9432 to port 9000 for my docker container.

The apache log shows:

```
 [Wed May 17 15:21:06.686610 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 1667573:tid 23434592974592] proxy_util.c(2850): [remote 76.182.65.97:35902] AH00947: connected / to localhost:9432
[Wed May 17 15:21:06.686721 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 1667573:tid 23434592974592] proxy_util.c(3326): AH02824: FCGI: connection established with [::1]:9432 (localhost:9432)
[Wed May 17 15:21:07.815663 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1667573:tid 23434592974592] [remote 76.182.65.97:35902] AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header
[Wed May 17 15:21:07.815707 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1667573:tid 23434592974592] (104)Connection reset by peer: [remote 76.182.65.97:35902] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

I have other web apps on Docker that I'd like to frontend with https, so solving this would help those cases, too.

Thanks!